# non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (unknown error) with a script that runs ok in btcdeb

Tags: script, raw-transaction, p2sh, p2wsh

after learning a lot about script (and playing with them on the testnet) i made a way longer script.

```
$ btc decodescript 7455886f94935688789352885279935b88946e935b88945187
{
  "asm": "OP_DEPTH 5 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_3DUP OP_SUB OP_ADD 6 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_OVER OP_ADD 2 OP_EQUALVERIFY 2 OP_PICK OP_ADD 11 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_SUB OP_2DUP OP_ADD 11 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_SUB 1 OP_EQUAL",
  ...
  "segwit": {
    ...
    "address": "tb1q2c0uglp5tg2dhnr3ejuwppalp9urdfu4cxnl2sc495vlzmjy2ggs2wk7ry",
    ...
  }
}
```

the solution to this script is `6` `9` `4` `2` `0`.

however, when redeeming the 1000 sat from the p2wsh address it gives me the error:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet sendrawtransaction 010000000001019f084303418f25b5a77f36b95f293b052e9d885d98020be3f66fb223939bbbe00000000000ffffffff018c030000000000001600140f4eb1382443259e6d295d8ddf1ade059e4b1f8c0601060109010401020100197455886f94935688789352885279935b88946e935b8894518700000000
error code: -26
error message:
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (unknown error)
```

i searched around a bit on bitcoin se and the only useful thing i could find was a [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/111011/non-mandatory-script-verify-flag-unknown-error) complaining about `OP_PICK`. Somebody knows how to fix this?

PS: i really don't care about 1000 test sat but just i want to fix this to learn from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by the same issue (minimal encoding) as [problem with unlocking P2WSH](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/111590/problem-with-unlocking-p2wsh). The [solution](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/111595/128539) Andrew Chow gave me there worked for me here too.

Answer (score 0):

I was the guy, who asked the other question.
In my case the problem was, that the operations left a unclean stack, which is technically ok, since the stack is not empty. But if I am correct its a non-standard transacition and will not be relayed by nodes.

In my case I had to finish with one element, which is not 0. And this was not possible in my script.

Comment: p2sh is not nonstandard. p2sh (or p2wsh) is the way to wrap nonstandard script in a script hash