# problem with unlocking P2WSH

Tags: script, raw-transaction, p2wsh

i made a P2WSH address with bitcoinjs-lib from a script. the same script results in the same address with bitcoin core. I made an unlocking script and tested the combination with `btcdeb` and everything looked fine, so i sent some sats to the address and tried unlocking it. however, bitcoin core gives me this error when trying to broadcast the transaction.

```
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (unknown error)
```

the script is made by adding `t` times `OP_OVER OP_SUB OP_1 OP_EQUALVERIFY` and `OP_0 OP_EQUAL` to the end

you can run the code by putting it in a file in `https://github.com/antonilol/btc_stuff` and running `npm i`. (for `bitcoinjs-lib` package and files `btc.js` and `btc2.js`) on a node running testnet

my code:

```
const { send } = require('./btc')();
const { bech32toScriptPubKey } = require('./btc2');
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
const network = bitcoin.networks.testnet;

const witnessScriptPiece = bitcoin.script.compile([
    bitcoin.opcodes.OP_OVER,
    bitcoin.opcodes.OP_SUB,
    bitcoin.opcodes.OP_1,
    bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUALVERIFY
]);

const l = witnessScriptPiece.length;

const witnessScriptEnd = bitcoin.script.compile([
    bitcoin.opcodes.OP_0,
    bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUAL
]);

const t = 3;

const witnessScript = Buffer.allocUnsafe(l * t + witnessScriptEnd.length);

for (var i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    witnessScriptPiece.copy(witnessScript, i * l);
}

witnessScriptEnd.copy(witnessScript, t * l);

console.log('Locking script: ' + witnessScript.toString('hex'));

console.log(
    'send 1000 sat to ' +
    bitcoin.payments.p2wsh({ redeem: { output: witnessScript, network }, network }).address
);

const tx = new bitcoin.Transaction(network);

// const txid = 'b37fc02fda463403a4d077863d163f6c2738659a4bba77284711ea8eeb95fc7d'; // t=17 vout=0
const txid = '407e7513afdd4baedeac62870acb7e426a6f7aa85ca45f7e54411e8b74d8876c'; // t=3 vout=1
const vout = 1;

tx.addInput(Buffer.from(txid, 'hex').reverse(), vout);
tx.setWitness(0, [
    ...Array(t + 1).fill().map((x, i) => {
        const b = Buffer.allocUnsafe(1);
        b.writeInt8(i);
        return b;
    }),
    witnessScript
]);

const fee_sat = 110;
const input_sat = 1000;

tx.addOutput(bech32toScriptPubKey('tb1q3my0fxc7n5sfx9c76p9mdyk6ly6j22wgp644q6'), input_sat-fee_sat);

send(tx.toHex()).then(console.log)
```

raw tx hex it produces for `t=3`:

`010000000001016c87d8748b1e41547e5fa45ca87a6f6a427ecb0a8762acdeae4bddaf13757e400100000000ffffffff017a030000000000001600148ec8f49b1e9d2093171ed04bb692daf9352529c80501000101010201030e789451887894518878945188008700000000`

`t=17`:

`010000000001017dfc95eb8eea11472877ba4b9a6538276c3f163d8677d0a4033446da2fc07fb30000000000ffffffff017a030000000000001600148ec8f49b1e9d2093171ed04bb692daf9352529c8130100010101020103010401050106010701080109010a010b010c010d010e010f01100111467894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188008700000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are encountering is the requirement for the minimal encoding of data. Specifically, your witness stack contains `0x00` for the number 0. However this is not the minimal encoding of 0. Rather the minimal encoding for 0 is an empty vector. So your transactions should actually be

```
010000000001016c87d8748b1e41547e5fa45ca87a6f6a427ecb0a8762acdeae4bddaf13757e400100000000ffffffff017a030000000000001600148ec8f49b1e9d2093171ed04bb692daf9352529c805000101010201030e789451887894518878945188008700000000
010000000001017dfc95eb8eea11472877ba4b9a6538276c3f163d8677d0a4033446da2fc07fb30000000000ffffffff017a030000000000001600148ec8f49b1e9d2093171ed04bb692daf9352529c81300010101020103010401050106010701080109010a010b010c010d010e010f01100111467894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188789451887894518878945188008700000000
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. i also have it fixed in my javascript code now! (allocate 0 bytes buffer if `i == 0`)